# Curves similarity metric

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, plane-geometry, applied-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I am working on an optical character recognition algorithm that takes vector data (i.e. polylines) as input rather than raster picture. E.g., we have N polyline samples, and when certain polyline is given as algorithm input we want to know which sample most likely it is.

My question is as follows: is there any metric of similarity between two polylines? I have an idea about it, but I wonder if that a form of some well-known method, or are there any alternative algorithms of recognizing curves in vector representation.

So my idea of similarity measurement:

- Move two curves so that their "center" points match.
- Measure the area formed by two curves (yellow on figure). The less
  area is - the more similar curves are.
- We can also consider curves length as metric.
  E.g., the area can be about zero, but one curve can be much longer
  than another and thus not similar to it.

[image]

Is that idea correct? Are there any other algorithms? Thanks.

Comment: For two sets $A,B\subset\mathbb R^2$, one possible metric would be $d(A,B)=\inf_fd_H(a,f(B))$, where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff metric and $I$ ranges through the isometries of the plane. (This resembles the Gromov-Hausdorff distance.) If you want, you can make $I$ include scaling (or other stuff) as well if it suits your purposes. Would something like this work for you?

Comment: At this stage this is a scientific question, not mathematical. What kind of lines do you have? Printed? Hand written? Artistic? Do you assume that they are about the same size? Are they oriented in the same way? Do they appear as material items seen from different angles and with distortions (like on a page which is not flat, at the inside margins)? Once the nature of the characters (or similar) is known then the algorithm is a relatively easy issue.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński The line is represented simply as an array of two-dimensional points {x, y}, where x and y are real values. In the real world it would be a finger stroke on an android tablet, for example.

Comment: Sometimes the available material circumstances are not sufficient to provide an adequate answer. It's a general  problem with the pattern recognition. One should also state if the objects to be recognized are for sure one or some may be false. In the case of characters one may be given an object which is just an accidental wiggle or a material flaw.

Comment: I agree with @WłodzimierzHolsztyński that the problem is not a mathematical one. Asking for mathematical ideas for measuring the difference would be ok at math.stackexchange, I think, so I voted to migrate the question there.

Comment: You may wish to compute the Frechet distance between curves, which can be computed in quadratic time.

Comment: Tom Crimmins in late 1970s had written a paper about character recognition by applying the Fourier analysis. Perhaps he assumed a closed curve, and looked at the Fourier coefficients as invariants.

Comment: Thus "b" and "q" are different, yes?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Yes.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński To be concrete, I am planning to use the algorithm to create a simple musical score editor for smartphones/tablets where user inputs note signs by his finger. Most used note signs are quite gemetrically simple, and it is a feasible restriction that user should not rotate symbols he inputs. Btw, you are right that it is not really strictly mathematical research question, but neither it is a pure programming question. I'll consider asking on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Oleg, thank you. A hand may be trembling. Thus smoothing algorithms can be useful (parallel processors are great for such operations :-). A brute force: one should have a large data base of standard images, one per character. One should also have a data base of operations. Than to a given input, after some preprocessing like smoothing, on could apply apply each of the operations and to compare it with each of the standard images. Here finally one needs an algorithm (distance and similar). Later one may look for intelligent/conceptual shortcuts i.e. trees of standard images & operations, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I may just expand upon Suvrit's suggestion, here is an image illustrating
the Fréchet distance,
the minimum length of a leash allowing a dog and its owner to walk
along the two curves without backtracking:

---

[image]

     

<sup>(Image from [Wouter Meulemans](http://www.win.tue.nl/~wmeulema/research.html).)</sup>

---

> Kevin Buchin, Maike Buchin, Wouter Meulemans, and Bettina Speckmann.
>   "Locally Correct Fréchet Matchings."
>   *Proceedings of the 20th European Symposium on Algorithms* (ESA 2012), LNCS 7501, pages 229-240, 2012. ([arXiv abstract link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6257))

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to measure distances between curves, but I do not think you need it.

Instead I would play with some functionals say total turn, number of inflection points and so on and check which of them best for your recognition problem.